# Why is my BottomBar in the middle of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, bottombar

I'm using both NavigationDrawer and BottomNavigationView. But after the add Navigation Drawer, position of Bottom Navigation is changed. How do I solve that? I assume this problem is caused by my xml files.

[image: BottomBar]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.example.yunus.ototakip.MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_bar"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_bar_drawer" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/beyaz"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/beyaz"
    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />
```

Comment: You know that `layout_alignParentBottom` is for `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach your `BottomNavigationView` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` (or whatever view group you've inside app_bar_navigation_bar layout) not `DrawerLayout` and add appropriate gravity tag.

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using either of the two=

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

or

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: I did. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_gravity="bottom" instead of layout_alignParentBottom as it is for RelativeLayout not android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

Comment: I get this error:BottomNavigationView at index 3 does not have a valid layout_gravity - must be Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT or Gravity.NO_GRAVITY